# Burninate the [html-table] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I'd like the [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table) tag to be burninated.
Because this tag somehow conveys the idea that it's OK to use tables in HTML, and everybody knows it's not. There is no legitimate use for tables. Tables should not be used for layout. They should not be used for lists. Nor for columns, vertical centering, input forms, etc. Indeed, they shouldn't be used at all.
We need to show people that they are only using tables because they fell into the trap of the tables' ease of use, versitality, straightforwardness and their willingess to do what you want, until you're hooked and you can't live without tables any more. Because that's the problem: tables are so damned *useful*.

So if we get rid of the [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table) tag, this is a signal to all the misguided users who want to ask a question about tables, that they shouldn't. That table-using users are not welcome in our community. Tables are evil! Tables are the Devil's own creation that should be eradicated completely in order to make this a better world!
And it follows that people who use tables are also evil. If we give out that signal consistently, maybe we can divert the poor souls back onto the right path. Some people may not even know they're being subverted by this hideous element, so they will need to be educated.
Perhaps even some people here who read this may think, huh, what's he talking about; tables aren't that bad are they? And that just shows how vicious they are, how well they can disguise themselves as benign. They will creep into your HTML pages almost without you noticing them. And they're addictive: once you start using tables, you won't be able to stop. I must admit I have been using tables in the past, but that's all behind me now. That was before I realised what an unforgivable sin I was committing. I have been off tables now for a while and feel a lot better about myself, about knowing I will never need to use one again, since I've discovered the CSS properties.

We pride ourselves in the quality of our questions and answers, and IMHO discouraging questions about this despicable element will greatly improve the average quality of the whole site.

Comment: I almost fell for this.  6/10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is no legitimate use for tables

Yes there is. Tables should indeed be used **for tabular data** because it makes semantic sense. Why would you have something like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="column"></div>
   <div class="column"></div>
   <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

When:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Makes it so much more obvious what that markup represents?

Also, I don't think we should kill tags just for bad practice. All sections of a programming language can potentially be used in the wrong way - it doesn't mean they're not an applicable topic for a question.

Comment: Or this is an April Fools' joke I'm completely missing....

Comment: Considering the user asking this question I'm inclined to think it is in fact a joke.

Comment: And I thought I had made it through today without falling for one. Rats.

Comment: May it be a comfort to you that it gained you rep, while I only lost on it.